# How can I change my program to let it display the output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to print out the happiest countries in the world for 2022, by receiving the data from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Happiness_Report?action=raw).  and then editing displaying the first 5 countries. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
content=$(curl -s "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Happiness_Report?action=raw")
lines=$(echo "$content" | grep '^\|' | sed -n '/2022/{n;p;}')
top_5=$(echo "$lines" | awk '{print $3}' | sort | head -n 5)
echo "$top_5"
```

However, when I run this code in Ubuntu, nothing shows up, its just blank, like this:

```
....(My computer server).....:~$ bash happy_countriesnew.sh
#(I'm expecting there to be a list here)
....(My computer server).....:~$
```

I'm expecting something like this instead of the blank space my terminal is displaying:

```
Finland
Norway
Denmark
Iceland
Switzerland
Netherlands
Canada
New Zealand
Sweden
Australia
```

What am I doing wrong and what should I change?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have, I've tried to change echo but to no avail. I'm just stuck on why there is no output when I run this in Ubuntu. Like literally, nothing shows up at all

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. You could start by checking what `content`  contains, what `lines`  contains,...

Answer (score 1):

`echo | grep | sed | awk` is a bit of an anti-pattern.  Typically, you want to refactor such pipelines to just be a call to `awk`.  In your case, it looks like your code that is attempting to extract the 2022 data is flawed.  The data is already sorted, so you can drop the sort and get the data you want with:

```
 sed -n '/^=== 2022 report/,/^=/{ s/}}//; /^|[12345]|/s/.*|//p; }'
```

The first portion (the `/^=== 2022 report/,/^=/`) tells `sed` to only work on lines between those that match the two given patterns, which is the data you are interested in.  The rest is just cleaning up and extracting just the country name, printing only those lines in which the 2nd field is exactly one of the single digits 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5.
Note that this is not terribly flexible, and it is difficult to modify it to print the top 7 or the top 12, so you might want something like:

```
sed -n '/^=== 2022 report/,/^=/{ s/}}//; /^|[[:digit:]]/s/.*|//p; }' | head -n 5
```

Note that it could be argued that `sed | head` is also a bit of an anti-pattern, but keeping track of lines of output in `sed` is tedious and the pipe to `head` is less egregious than attempting to write such code.

Comment: So the code bit that u've entered is part of lines right?

Comment: do u suggest that I rewrite lines to align with what u said or just edit the sed portion?

Comment: What I've written expects to take its input directly from curl: `curl ... | sed ...`.  If `lines` is supposed to just be the 2022 data, you could do `lines=$(echo "$content" | sed -n '/^=== 2022 report/,/^=/p')`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you see this error (but you are ignoring it)

```
grep: empty (sub)expression
```

the problem is with your `grep` expression, remove the ecape

```
lines=$(echo "$content" | grep '^|' | sed -n '/2022/{n;p;}')
```

and check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F"{{|}}|[|]" '/^=== 2022 rep/ {f=1} /^=== 2021 rep/ {f=0} {if(f==1 && /flag/) {print $6}}' <<<"$content" | head -n 5
Finland
Denmark
Iceland
Switzerland
Netherlands
```

`-F"{{|}}|[|]"` # set field separator to '{{' or '}}' or '|'

`/^=== 2022 rep/ {f=1}` # set flag if line starts with '=== 2022 rep'

`/^=== 2021 rep/ {f=0}` # unset flag if line starts with '=== 2021 rep'

`{if(f==1 && /flag/) {print $6}}'` # if `f` is set and line contains 'flag' text print 6th field

Note: Assumes "$content" variable is populated via `content=$(curl -s "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Happiness_Report?action=raw")`

-- or --

You could use bash command substitution and avoid the intermediate `content` variable altogether:

```
awk -F"{{|}}|[|]"  '/^=== 2022 rep/ {f=1} /^=== 2021 rep/ {f=0} {if(f==1 && /flag/) {print $6}}' < <(curl -s "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Happiness_Report?action=raw") | head -n 5
```

Output:

```
Finland
Denmark
Iceland
Switzerland
Netherlands
```

Comment: so in order to put this awk, do I have to remove everything under content?

Comment: or should I just add it at the end?

Comment: In your script you would replace everything under the `content=...` line with the single `awk` command.

Comment: Or avoid the intermediate `content` variable by using bash command substitution.  See updated answer for example.

Comment: when I try to run that, it sayd "head: invalid number of lines: ‘5\r’", do you know the source of that problem?

Comment: What did you try to run?  I cannot reproduce the error you mention.

Comment: I ran it on Ubuntu, shell script

Comment: are u getting the right response as I mentioned in my original question?

Comment: can you edit ur response and paste exactly what u would write in ur terminal, so that I can compare with what I have put into Ubuntu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251493/discussion-between-j-b-and-deezel).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> curl …………… | 
>
> gawk 'NF *= 2<NF' FS='^[|][1-5][|][|][{][{]flag[|]|[}][}]$' OFS=
> ```

```
Finland
Denmark
Iceland
Switzerland
Netherlands
```

If you wanna shrink it even further :

> ```
> mawk 'NF *= 2<NF' FS='^[|][1-5][|].+[|]|[}]+$' OFS=
> ```

this approach makes is easy to expand the list to, say, Top 17 :

> ```
> nawk 'NF *= 2<NF' FS='^[|]([1-9]|1[0-7])[|].+[|]|[}]+$' OFS=
> ```

```
     1  Finland
     2  Denmark
     3  Iceland
     4  Switzerland
     5  Netherlands
     6  Luxembourg
     7  Sweden
     8  Norway
     9  Israel
    10  New Zealand
    11  Austria
    12  Australia
    13  Ireland
    14  Germany
    15  Canada
    16  United States
    17  United Kingdom
```